# 'Open All' nested jQuery accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to open all nested accordions inside a jQuery accordion. 
Sample code -

I want to be able to open just the Nested accordions(Nested Heading) and not all accordions (Heading 2). Also how would I change the button from 'Expand all' to 'Collapse all' and then close the nested accordions when clicked again?

```
    <div class="accordion">
  <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <div><button type="button" class="expand2nd">Expand all</button>
       <div class="accordion">
         <h3>Nested Heading</h3>
           <div>Nested Title 1</div>
       <div class="accordion">
         <h3>Nested Heading 2</h3>
           <div>Nested Title 2</div>
       <div class="accordion">
         <h3>Nested Heading 3</h3>
           <div>Nested Title 3</div>
     </div>
  <h3>Heading 2</h3>
   <div>content<div>
</div>

$(".expand2nd").click(function (event) {
    $('.accordion .ui-accordion-header:not(.ui-state-active)').nextAll(':has(.accordion .ui-accordion-header)').slideDown();

    return false;
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: your accordions divs seems doesn't have a closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to declare a class of accordion in all of your child elements, just using the first accordion class declared will allow jquery to manipulate them. Check out https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ example, it does what you specifically are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Even if I remove the classes from the divs the function still expands all accordions, I only want to expand the nested accordions. How would I target just the nested accordions?

Comment: what libraries are you using?